# Do multiple GA codes increase a website bounce rate to 100%?

Tags: google-analytics

Help! My client’s website has a bounce rate of 100% for Organic, Paid and Referral channels. Also, has nearly 90% of bounce rate to the rest of the channels. I verified that the GA code is implemented correctly but tag assistant shows 10 GA tags with 2 errors. Does the bounce rate has anything to do with multiple GA tags?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related.

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the site. As @michele-pisani says, this is probably note related to multiple GA codes. How much traffic are we talking about? Is it possibly real bounced sessions? Are you using any kind of non-standard URL system or UTM tracking within the site? A possible answer is that something is breaking the session between pageviews.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The site is quite new and no, we're not using any kind of non-standard URL system or UTM tracking. I believe we should look into how pageviews and sessions are being tracked. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

100% bounce rate it means not that you have multiple codes on the page rather than the code is not in all the pages or is not always executed or is a badly traced onepage or actually that users bounce.

Comment: Thanks, Michele. The thing is, the GA code is in the head tag so it is implemented on all the pages. Please elaborate on "a badly traced one page"